# apache2 is not a native service

Tags: 16.04, apache2

I am trying to enable apache2 after installing it in my OS. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. After installing, I'e given these orders in the console -

```
sudo systemctl start apache2
sudo systemctl restart apache2
sudo systemctl enable apache2
```

But enable command has failed and this error is showing -

```
apache2.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable apache2
```

It has enabled apache2 service but in another way. Why it is showing apache2.service is not a native service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time it happens because configuration file has syntax error. To see what is the problem run

```
journalctl | tail
```

Or

```
apache2ctl configtest
```

It will show you which line caused the problem.

If it doesn't have syntax problem, Remove and install it again:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
sudo apt-get remove apache2
sudo apt-get purge libapache2-mod-php*
sudo apt-get purge php*
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: it showing `Syntax OK` but still getting the same error

Comment: I also had `Syntax OK`, but solved the issue by reinstalling apache as described in the last paragraph.