# apache2.service is not a native service (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: server, apache2, services

My os is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I installed apache2 from ubuntu repositories. 
After applying this command:

> sudo systemctl enable apache2

I get following error:

> apache2.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable apache2

Which is not satisfying me at all.
These commands are executed without any problems:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2 
sudo systemctl start apache2
```

**journalctl -ex** and **apache2ctl configtest** say nothing.

```
journalctl -ex output:
бер 01 21:24:47 medion-laptop NetworkManager[917]: <info>  [1519932287.3295]   lease time 7200
    бер 01 21:24:47 medion-laptop NetworkManager[917]: <info>  [1519932287.3298]   nameserver '192.168.0.1'
    бер 01 21:24:47 medion-laptop NetworkManager[917]: <info>  [1519932287.3300] dhcp4 (wlp8s0): state changed bound -> bound
    бер 01 21:24:47 medion-laptop dbus[908]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-d
    бер 01 21:24:47 medion-laptop systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
    -- Subject: Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun start-up
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    -- 
    -- 
Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun starting up.
    бер 01 21:24:47 medion-laptop dbus[908]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
    бер 01 21:24:47 medion-laptop nm-dispatcher[8011]: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlp8s0]: new request (1 scripts)
    бер 01 21:24:47 medion-laptop nm-dispatcher[8011]: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlp8s0]: start running ordered scripts...
    бер 01 21:24:47 medion-laptop systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
    -- Subject: Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has finished start-up
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    -- 
    -- Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has finished starting up.
    -- 
    -- The start-up result is done.
    бер 01 21:24:47 medion-laptop dhclient[1073]: bound to 192.168.0.102 -- renewal in 2970 seconds.
    бер 01 21:33:40 medion-laptop org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources5[1711]: ** (evolution-source-registry:1911): WARNING **: secret_service_search_sy


medion@medion-laptop:~$ apache2ctl configtest
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
```

Also I tried to reinstall my apache2 ([like here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834458/apache2-is-not-a-native-service?newreg=fa54c99182944e1cb2cd683ddedea467)), but the error still come up.

So after searching about this issue, I found out that this problem usually appear when the configuration file has syntax error. But I don't have anything like that, probably cause I have installed my apache2 a few minutes ago and never had a deal with apache2's configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is apache running?  This error does not reflect any issue with apache itself, but it is informing you that even though you used a systemd command to enable the service, it's actually invoking a SysVinit style script.  Provided apache is running correctly you can safely ignore this error.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error but an information that Ubuntu 16.04 still uses a SysV init style file to start Apache, and systemd just wraps that.

From `/lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install`:

```
# This script is called by "systemctl enable/disable" when the given unit is a
# SysV init.d script. It needs to call the distribution's mechanism for
# enabling/disabling those, such as chkconfig, update-rc.d, or similar.
```